# How to calculate voltage and current of a circuit with input / output MCU pins

Tags: microcontroller, power, voltage-regulator, switches, low-power

I would like to know the method to calculate both voltage and current in a circuit that use MCU input / output pins

In this example, how can we find the V / A of all resistances and Capacitors..

Also how to determine the voltage / Current in our input pin.. or EN pin...

[image: Simple Circuit]

Comment: Output pins are *forcing* voltage. Input pins are usually buffered, so you can assume they are not sourcing/sinking any current (but you should consult the datasheet for the electrical model).

Comment: Where did this circuit come from? It really doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Matt, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The current into or out of the enable pin will be determined by the design of the LDO, so you need to examine the datasheet for the LDO.

Once you know the voltage-current characteristic (and some things about the MCU- see below) you can calculate the current and voltage for any given situation. I would say there are four possibilities for the enable pin given the switch may be pressed or not, and the MCU output may be high or not.

The input pin would not normally figure into this, but I would divine from this particular circuit that the MCU may be switching its own power, so there may be a case where significant current will flow into input pin (likely briefly as the LDO and MCU power up). For this circuit to be useful it would also probably have an internal (or not-shown external) pull-down resistor on the MCU input- probably enabled by firmware. Perhaps 50K or something like that. Realize that this is totally an educated guess on my part and what actually happens will depend on things not shown in your schematic.

The capacitors are across fixed supplies so ideally they conduct no current except when the power comes on. If you look a bit closer, they will conduct current depending on the (not shown) loads during normal operation since the source voltage and the LDO will have some non-zero output impedance that varies with frequency.

Answer (score 0):

The method used to calculate this is described in any basic book about electronics. EEs use Kirchhoff's current and voltage laws to calculate the currents and voltages together with Ohm's law.

That sounds more difficult than it is. I could explain: take this voltage, devide by that, etc. But then I'm telling you how to solve **this** particular circuit and that is just ne applying those Laws and this teaches you nothing about how to use those laws yourself.

So, get a textbook about KVL and KCL or search this site as you're not the first who needs to learn this. Beware that the examples you will see used in books do not relate directly to the circuit you included above. But the point of the "weird" circuits in the books is to teach you the method and that is what you're asking if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Basically, you draw the circuit and write (in the circuit) all the voltages, currents and resistor values which you know. Then by applying the three laws try to determine the unknown parameters. It takes some practice but once you understand how it works it is very easy.